# My father is too slow at his daily routine

Tags: daily-routine

I don't know why my dad is sooooooo slow. He wakes up late, washes his face for 10 minutes, brushes his teeth for 20 min, has his tea for 10-20 min, shaves for 20min, baths for 20-30 min, applies creams on his face for 10 min, slow in discussion making, and finally has his lunch at 3:00pm. If a normal person takes 2min to complete a job he take 20min to complete the same. I don't know why is he like this.

Is there any way I can make him faster?

Comment: How old is he? How old are you? Does he have any disabilities? Does the slowness have a negative impact on his quality of life? Does *he* want to do things faster?

Comment: He is 48 and is slow from his childhood and highly affects our daily routine. Also because of that he cant accomplish his work traget at his office.

Comment: Are you an adult or a child? Has he asked you to help him with this? What does he want?

Comment: I m his son. No he never asked me to help and doesn't wants to be helped he likes how he is. Disturbingly he enjoys when he is alone without hos family.

Comment: If he doesn't _want_ to be helped, I'm not sure if there's much you can do. This might be a better question at [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) -- even though this is a parent-child relationship, I'm unsure how to bring parenting into it.

Comment: This is not a parenting question.

Comment: I tried to talk with my father about he being slower and how it affects our daily routine, but he doesn't seem to change.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a parenting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way I can make him faster?

Among the many, many things you'll learn as you age, one of the most important lessons is that you can't control other people, you can only control yourself.

Commonly, people trying to get other people to change their behavior try talking, explaining, getting angry, begging, shaming, bribing, etc. All this will usually have little lasting effect on someone's behavior; the person who has the problem must recognize the behavior as a problem that *they* want to change. When that behavior hurts us in some way, this is very difficult to accept. You've already stated that he doesn't seem to wish to change.

You can try calmly discussing with your father how his actions have a negative impact on you, for example, if his monopolization of the bathroom is making you late for school, you can try to *negotiate* some course of action that involves some give and take on both of your parts.

Probably the best thing that can come out of this is to really remember how your father's actions make you feel, why they make you feel this way, and determine that *you* won't do this to anyone else, especially your spouse and your children. Learning from the mistakes of others is a valuable life skill.

This isn't a very helpful answer, and I'm sorry for that. The only other thing I'd suggest is that he might benefit from a blood test to determine if he has hypothyroidism, which can physically slow people down in the way you describe. If he's always been this way, however, it's not likely that it's a medical condition.

Comment: Update: My father didn't change a bit. I think now i have to live with this.

Comment: @KartikPillai - I'm sorry to hear that. :( It does make one feel small when someone important has no wish to treat us better.

Answer (score 0):

at 48 there is likely a more compelling reason. It may be that he is slow in general, however when someone is not happy with their life, they are in no rush to be reminded of it, hence the lengthy warm up to getting his day started and to completing his tasks at work.

He probably hates his job but feels compelled to stay in it to support the family.

I don't have a solution to fix the problem, but think outside the box. Being extra slow is a way to procrastinate and we procrastinate doing the things we dislike.